# Function parameter to create JSON property / object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

So basically make this work:

```
function removeTestObjects(collection, property, value) {
  return db.collection(collection).remove({property: value}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

When i pass a string as property it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `bracket notation`. Bracket notation should be used when property names are to be dynamically determined.

```
return db.collection(collection).remove({[property]: value}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```